# What is a good naming convention for Rails custom controller actions regarding formulation (noun vs verb)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, crud, convention

When defining new **actions** in controllers I often find myself asking how should I formulate the name of the action correctly. Rails default CRUD actions all seem to follow the pattern of **verb** (*new, create, edit, update, destroy, index*) but is it a bad habit to use a noun? For ex. *payment_history*?

I found a lot of [information](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e) describing the naming conventions for different files and classes and regarding the proper syntax but none about controller#actions from formulation part.

**EDIT:** I am asking about custom-defined actions not renaming the Rails default CRUD actions.

Comment: Use a meaningful name and ask yourself if the route seems user friendly and says what exactly the route/action does

Comment: That's how I've decided so far but it would be good to know if there is any good convention about this or any other thoughts.

Comment: Downvoter - how can the question be improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, important thing about choosing name of the action should not be based on whether it is a noun or a verb, the name of the action should describe the behavior of the action itself, whether it calculates/gets/loads/renders/etc something. So that, when another person (or you after a long time) reads the code, he/she should be able to easily understand what is this action used for and what is expected result from this action.

Otherwise you could just name it is as * whatever * since ruby doesn't prohibit you to do so.

As example we can take a look at `payment_history` and `list_payment_history`. If I am reading the code and see action named `list_payment_history`, I understand that it **lists** the history, even without looking at the code I understand the purpose of the action. However if I see `payment_history`, I can only understand that it has something to do with history, not the exact meaning, does it show history, or may be sort history, archive history... no concrete understanding towards the purpose of the action.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're following the conventional RESTful methodology, it is going to be easiest to follow the convention of `index`, `show`, `new/create`, `edit/update` and `destroy`. That is, unless you have a well-grounded reason not to, but then you ought to be able to justify to yourself and possible other developers *why* the default action names are not sufficient.

Using the default method names, you get a lot of the routing etc. stuff "for free", as Rails assumes you're following the convention. Also, do note that things that might not immediately sound like "resources" can often easily be modeled as such, e.g. your example "`payment_history`" may well be a subresource of another resource (a `User`?), in which  case you'd have a singular nested route such as `GET /users/{user_id}/payment_history`. This route would then call `PaymentHistoryController#show`, as demonstrated in the [Rails guide section on singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).

Comment: Just to clarify: I don't want to rename the Rails default routes and actions. I have a case of defining new custom controller action. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but what I was saying is that you might want to take a step back and consider do you *really* need to invent a new name for the action, as you can usually model the system in REST with the default method names.

Comment: There are some cases when the functionality becomes difficult enough to need some new custom actions. For ex. a blog app, where one might want to archive posts that are older than 1 year: do you name the action as **archive** or **archivation**?

Comment: Thing is, is that a controller action or something that runs as a scheduled job? Also, assuming it was indeed a controller concern, I might model it as a resource of it's own, i.e. `POST /archive`, where the action would be handled by `ArchiveController#create`. However, if you really want to decide between action names `archive` and `archivation`, then I would definitely say `archive` is the way to go.

Comment: The archive was just an example of possible naming issue. But still for me the question remains - noun vs verb, or it really doesn't matter? As long as the route is logical and understandable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it matters so much, though in general I think you're looking for a verb. Your models are typically nouns, and controllers  define actions.

Answer (score -3):

**Controllers In rails acoording to my reading and experience**

Controller class names use **CamelCase** and have **Controller** as a suffix. The Controller suffix is always **singular**. The name of the resource is usually **plural**.

Controller actions use **snake_case and usually match the standard route names Rails defines** (index, show, new, create, edit, update, delete).

Controller files go in **app/controllers/#{resource_name}_controller.rb.**

Example:

```
# app/controllers/bigfoot_sightings_controller.rb
BigfootSightingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # ...
  end
  def show
    # ...
  end
  # etc
end
# app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # ...
  end
  # etc
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But my question was more about the best naming standard regarding formulation (verb vs noun, for ex: **list_payment_history** vs just **payment_history**).